# redis has timeouts every 5-7 minutes

Tags: python, networking, redis

I have install a redis server using google click to deploy. It has been unstable. Here is the health check i'm checking every minute:

```
redisClient = redis.StrictRedis(host = config['redis']['host'], port = config['redis']['port'], socket_timeout = 3)
redisClientConnection.get('bla_bla')
```

so I decided to install a new. This is his redis.conf file.

```
    daemonize yes
    pidfile /var/run/redis.pid
    port 6379
    tcp-backlog 511
    timeout 0
    tcp-keepalive 0
    loglevel notice
    logfile ""
    databases 16
    #save 900 1
    #save 300 10
    #save 60 10000
    stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
    rdbcompression yes
    rdbchecksum yes
    dbfilename dump.rdb
    dir ./
    slave-serve-stale-data yes
    slave-read-only yes
    repl-diskless-sync no
    repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
    repl-ping-slave-period 10
    repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
    slave-priority 100
    # maxmemory-samples 3
    appendonly no
    appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
    # appendfsync always
    appendfsync everysec
    # appendfsync no
    no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
    auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
    auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
    aof-load-truncated yes
    lua-time-limit 5000
    slowlog-max-len 128
    notify-keyspace-events ""
    list-max-ziplist-entries 512
    list-max-ziplist-value 64
    zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
    zset-max-ziplist-value 64
    hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
    activerehashing yes
    client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
    client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
    client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
    aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
```

It still fails due to a timeout every 10 7 minutes in average (2 is fail):

```
last execution2015-03-18 09:14:09
history[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0]
```

My app has 10 clients connected to redis using `client list`

you can see in my conf that I have canceled the persistance (save). I only use redis as cache. 
my question is: **Why Is timeouting every ~5-7 mins**

here is the error and the stack trace:
`TimeoutError: Timeout reading from socket`

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "healthCheck.py", line 14, in get redisClientConnection.get('bla_bla') File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 863, in get return self.execute_command('GET', name) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 565, in execute_command return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 577, in parse_response response = connection.read_response() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 569, in read_response response = self._parser.read_response() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 224, in read_response response = self._buffer.readline() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 162, in readline self._read_from_socket() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 133, in _read_from_socket raise TimeoutError("Timeout reading from socket") TimeoutError: Timeout reading from socket
```

**Edit:**
I've added a health check on the actual redis server:
`check-app-running.rb`

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
exec "redis-cli set mykey somevalue"
exec "redis-cli get mykey"
exit 0
```

and it's running fine:

```
last execution2015-03-18 10:14:51
history[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

So now I suspect the network. any ideas??

Comment: Similar issue here, but using Azure Redis, how did you solved?

Comment: I had a similar problem with memcache a while ago, I fixed it by constantly pinging the memcache server.  Once the ping started failing, I had proof to bring to the network administrator.  The machine was replaced my problem went away.